# How to animate an element so it loops inside its parent in HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve an animation similar to the animation present in the "scroll down icon" [at this page](https://searchingforsyria.org/en/what-was-syria-like-before-the-war/).

Here's my attempt at it:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

@keyframes anim {
   0% { top: 18% }
   30% { top: 18% }
   50% { top: 100% }
   51% { top: -50% }
   70% { top: 18% }
   100% { top: 18% }
}

#scroll-down-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  border: 2.3px solid white;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 64px;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  left: 0;
  top: 18%;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 1.75s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-down-icon"><h1>╲╱</h1></div>
```

However the code above doesn't make the the `h1` really "loop" inside the `#scroll-down-icon div`.

How would I address this issue and create an effect similar to the one present in the page using CSS & HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

@keyframes anim {
   0% { top: 18% }
   30% { top: 18% }
   50% { top: 100% }
   51% { top: -50% }
   70% { top: 18% }
   100% { top: 18% }
}

#scroll-down-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  border: 2.3px solid white;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 64px;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  left: 0;
  top: 18%;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 1.75s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}  
 
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-down-icon"><h1>╲╱</h1></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it :). Didn't know you could use overflow like that O.o.

Comment: @Polygons ,You are Welcome.